# save ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> android

Tags: android, arraylist, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using google maps v2 and everytime I parse same json from assets folder and use to represent it on the map .I am storing all the json values into `ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> myarraylist ;` I would like to store the same into android.
I really appreciate any way to do so .I only know to store strings and boolean into sharedpreferences.Please help me out.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you have the resource saved in the assets of your app, why do you want to deserialize it and then serialize it back again? Is the user allowed to input data and you want to save it?

Comment: I have it as json but I would like it to ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> arraylist .so that the data is already parsed and hence would take less time to add polygons on map.

Comment: trying to implement in the lines of http://ashoksubha.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-array-list-stored-synchronized.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use gson.jar to store class objects into SharedPreferences. You can downlaod this jar from here https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

```
SharedPreferences  mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To Save

```
 Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson("MyObject");
 prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
 prefsEditor.commit();
```

To Retreive

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = mPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
    MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```

To Save List of user-defined objects to SharedPreferences. for example

```
public static final String CONNECTIONS = "connections";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

User entity = new User();
// ... set entity fields

List<Connection> connections = entity.getConnections();
// convert java object to JSON format,
// and returned as JSON formatted string
String connectionsJSONString = new Gson().toJson(connections);
editor.putString(CONNECTIONS, connectionsJSONString);
editor.commit();
```

To Get List of user-defined objects from SharedPreferences

```
String connectionsJSONString = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString(CONNECTIONS, null);
Type type = new TypeToken < List < Connection >> () {}.getType();
List < Connection > connections = new Gson().fromJson(connectionsJSONString, type)
```

Comment: I have never used GSON can you direct me to a tutorial to implement GSON in my code.Thanks Nitesh will try to implement the same

Comment: try this...http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Comment: Also Can I store the entire ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> arraylist into GSON directly ?

Comment: yes you can ...just give it a try...you just need to tweak this code a bit...please dont forget to accept this answer if this answer helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html for details on all of them.

Comment: can i store it on a text file ? ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> arraylist;

Comment: I'm sure you could do that, but this won't really be different to having them in the assets as you already do...Or do you change the data? In that case I'd suggest using a database. Or, depending on the complexity of the data you store in the objects, shared preferences (you can put all kind of primitive data in there: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html ).

Comment: trying to implement in the lines of http://ashoksubha.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-array-list-stored-synchronized.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll ever come up with a format that will improve performance from the user point of view - but you can try the `Serializable` way -  make sure all Objects in your Map are Serializable - and store the binary blob in a file in the internal storage